# Standardize an RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have an RDD of doubles and I want to “standardize” it as follows:

1. Compute the mean and sd for each col
2. For each col, subtract the column mean from each entry and divide the result by the column sd

Can this be done efficiently and easily (without converting the RDD into a double array at any stage)?

Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 5):

You can use StandardScaler from Spark itself

```
/**
 * Standardizes features by removing the mean and scaling to unit variance 
 * using column summary
 */

  import org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.StandardScaler
  import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
  import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

  val data: RDD[Vector] = ???
  val scaler = new StandardScaler(true, true).fit(data)

  data.foreach { vector =>
    val scaled = scaler.transform(vector)
  }
```

Comment: I guess you want to do `data.map` instead of `foreach`